# Admob apears in xml but not in the actual application

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, admob

Hello I have followed a video on youtube exactly on how to add admob.

On the xml it shows that Ads By Google

What I have in the xml is

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools

xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

layout hight....

layour width...
```

`orientaiton`...

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@id/adView"
ads:adUnitId="....."

ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

In the menafist 
I added the permission for both the network and Internet

I also added

```
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"

android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

In my admob account I can see impression requests. Again the app all what I see is just a blank space where the add supposed to be viewed. I also added the google play services. I followed this video on Youtube AdMob Android tutorial working (google play)

Though they say it is not necessary but I have this on my Java class as it is described in the tutorial

```
// Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
    AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

IF SOMEBODY CAN LINK ME TO ANOTHER METHOD THAT IS GURANTEED I CAN DO EVERYTHING FROM SCRATCH. BUT PLEASE JUST GUARANTEED WITH THE NEW ADMOB FEATURE I TRIED TONS OF THEM

Comment: What is the question? What does your logcat say? What happens is you ask for test ads?

Comment: My question is why my add does not show on the real application and just appear on my xml layout. I don't get any errors in logcat.

Comment: Not asking for errors in logcat. Admob post messages when an ad is fetched. You will see whether one is and/or whether it could be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed what this person did and it just worked fine, thanks God!!! took a lot of time

[I can't get the new admob's to work with my application after countless hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141817/i-cant-get-the-new-admobs-to-work-with-my-application-after-countless-hours)